# How can I convert a list of rules to a list of numerical values?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, rule

`NSolve` gave this list of rules:

```
{{{v -> -48.6233, w -> 0.326367}}, {{v -> -54.547, 
   w -> 0.129048}}, {{v -> -62.6149, w -> 0.0286653}}}
```

How do I convert this to a list of values

```
{{ -48.6233, 0.326367}, {-54.547, 
   0.129048}, {-62.6149, 0.0286653}}
```

to be used in `Plot`?

Comment: `NSolveValues`?

Comment: `{v, w} /. {{{v -> -48.6233, w -> 0.326367}}, {{v -> -54.547, 
     w -> 0.129048}}, {{v -> -62.6149, w -> 0.0286653}}} // 
 Flatten[#, 1] &`

Comment: If you can't use `NSolveValues`, then you can just use `Part` to extract the second part of each `Rule` (you'll need to descend down the expression). Or even use `Cases`.

Comment: `First@*Values /@ {{{v -> -48.6233, w -> 0.326367}}, {{v -> -54.547, 
    w -> 0.129048}}, {{v -> -62.6149, w -> 0.0286653}}}`

Comment: `{v, w} /. #[[1]] & /@ {{{v -> -48.6233, w -> 0.326367}}, {{v -> -54.547, w -> 0.129048}}, {{v -> -62.6149, w -> 0.0286653}}}`

Comment: `lst[[All,1,All,2]]=(Values@lst)[[All,1]]==want`

Comment: I notice that you did not Accept an answer to this question. Is there something that remains to be addressed?

Comment: Hello eldo, I don't know how to "Accept an answer".  I am using the first suggestion above, from Syed. And have looked at the others with great interest. I have learnt a lot about Mathematica from these suggestions. And as I wrote in a comment, I thanked the suggestion authors.

Answer (score 5):

```
list =
  {{{v -> -48.6233, w -> 0.326367}},
   {{v -> -54.547, w -> 0.129048}},
   {{v -> -62.6149, w -> 0.0286653}}};

ListPlot[Values /@ list,
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
rules = {{{v -> -48.6233, w -> 0.326367}}, 
         {{v -> -54.547, w -> 0.129048}},
         {{v -> -62.6149, w -> 0.0286653}}};

pts = rules /. Rule[lhs_, rhs_] :> rhs

 (*{{{-48.6233, 0.326367}}, {{-54.547, 0.129048}}, {{-62.6149, 0.0286653}}}*)

 ListPlot[pts, 
          BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],
          Frame -> True, 
          AspectRatio -> 1, 
          GridLines -> Automatic
         ]
```

[image]